# MySQL Compare Result in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I imagine I'm missing something pretty obvious here.

I'm trying to display a list of 'bookings' where the total charges is higher than the total payments for the booking. The charges and payments are stored in separate tables linked using foreign keys.

**My query so far is:**

```
SELECT `booking`.`id`,
SUM(`booking_charge`.`amount`) AS `charges`,
SUM(`booking_payment`.`amount`) AS `payments`

FROM `booking`
LEFT JOIN `booking_charge` ON `booking`.`id` = `booking_charge`.`booking_id`
LEFT JOIN `booking_payment` ON `booking`.`id` = `booking_payment`.`booking_id`

WHERE `charges` > `payments` ///this is the incorrect part

GROUP BY `booking`.`id`
```

**My tables look something like this:**

```
Booking (ID)

Booking_Charge (Booking_ID, Amount)

Booking_Payment (Booking_ID, Amount)
```

MySQL doesn't seem to like comparing the results from these two tables, I'm not sure what I'm missing but I'm sure it's something which would be possible.

Comment: no errors?, names aren't ambiguous?

Comment: I thought that too, that's why I ended up putting the `booking_charge`... and `booking_payment` table names in before the `amount`.

But that doesn't seem to help either way. SQL is complaining about Unknown column 'charges' in 'where clause'...which I suppose is because `charges` is created as a column during the query itself.

Comment: try removing the `WHERE charges > payments` and add `HAVING charges > payments` at the very end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` like this

```
SELECT `booking`.`id`,
SUM(`booking_charge`.`amount`) AS `charges`,
SUM(`booking_payment`.`amount`) AS `payments`
FROM `booking`
LEFT JOIN `booking_charge` ON `booking`.`id` = `booking_charge`.`booking_id`
LEFT JOIN `booking_payment` ON `booking`.`id` = `booking_payment`.`booking_id`
GROUP BY `booking`.`id`
HAVING `charges` > `payments`
```

Comment: I had no idea having even existed, worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: This doesn't address the pernicious problem of the cross join (partial Cartesian product) between _charge and _booking. And it doesn't address the case when there are no rows in _payment (with non-null value of amount) for a given booking_id (this query won't return that row).

Comment: Thanks @spencer7593 - I bumped into that issue too actually, I kind of forgot about it in the excitement.

My workaround was to just use:
ifnull(SUM(`booking_charge`.`amount`),0) AS `charges`,
ifnull(SUM(`booking_payment`.`amount`),0) AS `payments`,

Comment: @ScottCampbell: but that doesn't address the issue of having one row in charge for $40 and two rows in payment for $20 each. This query is going to return charges as $80 (2 x $40). If there are five rows in payments of $10 each, this query will return $200 for charges (5 x $40).

Comment: @spencer7593
oh drat, I didn't pick up on that before. Are you aware of any potential ways around this?

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems with the query is the cross join between rows from  `_charge` and rows from `_payment`.  It's a semi-Cartesian join.  Each row returned from `_charge` will be matched with each row returned from `_payment`, for a given `booking_id`.

Consider a simple example:

Let's put a single row in `_charge` for $40 for a particular `booking_id`.

And put two rows into `_payment` for $20 each, for the same `booking_id`.

The query will would return total charges of $80. (= 2 x $40).  If there were instead five rows in \'_payment\' for $10 each, the query would return a total charges of $200 ( = 5 x $40)

There's a couple of approaches to addressing that issue. One approach is to do the aggregation in an inline view, and return the total of the charges and payments as a single row for each booking_id, and then join those to the booking table. With at most one row per booking_id, the cross join doesn't give rise to the problem of "duplicating" rows from _charge and/or _payment.

For example:

```
  SELECT b.id
       , IFNULL(c.amt,0)  AS charges
       , IFNULL(p.amt,0)  AS payments
    FROM booking b
    LEFT
    JOIN ( SELECT bc.booking_id
                , SUM(bc.amount) AS amt
             FROM booking_charge bc
            GROUP BY bc.booking_id
         ) c
      ON c.booking_id = b.id
    LEFT
    JOIN ( SELECT bp.booking_id
                , SUM(bp.amount) AS amt
             FROM booking_payment bp
            GROUP BY bp.booking_id
         ) p
      ON p.booking_id = b.id
   WHERE IFNULL(c.amt,0) > IFNULL(p.amt,0)
```

We could make use of a HAVING clause, in place of the WHERE.

---

The query in this answer is not the only way to get the result, nor is it the most efficient. There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this. I'm grateful you noticed as I worry my testing might not have noticed the previous issue you mentioned. I've tested it with a range of values and it seems to work perfectly. Thanks again!